# Reproduce Production environment in a Rake Task in Rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, production-environment

I'm trying to copy all my production database (that I have in Mongo) to my staging environment. So I'm trying to build a task. First I need to connect to production environment to be able to access to all my models in production (Model.all.each...) But I don't know how to reproduce the production environment. I know in console I can do 'export RAILS_ENV=heroku_production' but I don't know how to do it inside a Rake Task. This is what I'm trying for now but it does not work because I print Rails.env and it prints "development"...so I'm a bit lost

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :sync_production_staging do
    desc "Copy production database to staging"
    task :staging => :environment do

      system "export RAILS_ENV=heroku_production"

      ap Rails.env

      ap User.all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you are trying to clone your db from Heroku to your local?

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that copies my database from heroku to my local its a really strait forward process, I am sorry that this is PG and not mongo but I am sure that this should help

```
#lib/tasks/db.rake
namespace :db do
  desc "Import most recent database dump"
  task :import_from_prod => :environment do
    puts 'heroku run pg:backups capture --app sushi-prod'
    restore_backup 'sushi-prod'
  end

  def path_to_heroku
    ['/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku', '/usr/local/bin/heroku'].detect {|path| File.exists?(path)}
  end

  def heroku(command, site)
    `GEM_HOME='' BUNDLE_GEMFILE='' GEM_PATH='' RUBYOPT='' #{path_to_heroku} #{command} -a #{site}`
  end

  def restore_backup(site = 'sushi-prod')
    dump_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/postgres.dump"
    unless File.exists?(dump_file)
      pgbackups_url = heroku('pg:backups public-url -q', site).chomp
      puts "curl -o #{dump_file} #{pgbackups_url}"
      system "curl -o #{dump_file} '#{pgbackups_url}'"
    end
    database_config = YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")).with_indifferent_access
    dev_db = database_config[Rails.env]
    system "pg_restore -d #{dev_db[:database]} -c #{dump_file}".gsub(/\s+/,' ')
    puts
    puts "'rm #{dump_file}' to redownload postgres dump."
    puts "Done!"
  end
end
```